# How to give Sequel#execute a block on a simple select?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm executing a simple query vis Sequel like such:

```
result = db.execute("SELECT some_int_colum FROM some_system_table WHERE some_column = 'some_value';")
```

In a psql session, it returns the expected value but when run through the Sequel Postgres adapter it returns the number of resulting rows, not the value.

From the source ([reference](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb#L155-L157)):

> ```
>  # Execute the given SQL with this connection.  If a block is given,
>  # yield the results, otherwise, return the number of changed rows.
> ```

That clearly explains the why, but how is a block given to the execute method in this scenario?

Comment: Tip: You don't need `;` when executing queries programmatically. It's only necessary in a CLI-type environment to delimit one query from the next.

Comment: Do you mean `db.execute(...) do |result|`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dataset#fetch` ([reference](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/database/dataset.rb#L49-L53)) is a more appropriate method to execute arbitrary sql and return a single or set of values. In the above example, where only a single return value is expected it would look something like this:

```
result = db.fetch("SELECT some_int_colum FROM some_system_table WHERE some_column = 'some_value'").all.first.values.first
```

Comment: You can also do something like `DB[:some_table].where(some_column: 'some').select(:some_column).first[:some_column]`